# Mangto Multi Store -> Checkout -> Shipment Methods not showing for additional domains

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, e-commerce

- Magento version :1.4.0.1
- Multi Store setup :

  - main domain = a.com
  - domain add-on 1 = b.com
  - domain add-on 2 = c.com

Everything is working good until you try to checkout, on `a.com` you get the shipment methods ( flat rate) but on `b.com` and `c.com` you don't get anything.

In the admin panel everything is set-up like on `a.com`, I have since tried to debug using `Mage::log($result);` in the file `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php` 
in function  `public function saveBillingAction()` .

This is what I have in `system.log` for site `a.com`

```
2011-07-20T10:34:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [goto_section] => shipping_method
    [update_section] => Array
        (
            [name] => shipping-method
            [html] => <!--<dl class="sp-methods">//-->
            <h2 style="padding-left:3px;">Ground Shipping</h2>

            <ol>
                            <li>
                                                                                                                            <span class="no-display"><input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="tablerate_bestway" id="s_method_tablerate_bestway" checked="checked" class="radio" /></span>
                                                                                                                                <label for="s_method_tablerate_bestway">Flat Rate                                                                        <span class="price">$25.00</span>                                                </label>

                                   </li>
                        </ol>


        )

    [allow_sections] => Array
        (
            [0] => shipping
        )

    [duplicateBillingInfo] => true
)
```

And in `system.log` for site `b.com` and `c.com` I have :

```
2011-07-20T10:31:19+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [goto_section] => shipping_method
    [update_section] => Array
        (
            [name] => shipping-method
            [html] => <!--<dl class="sp-methods">//-->

        )

    [allow_sections] => Array
        (
            [0] => shipping
        )

    [duplicateBillingInfo] => true
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue recently and wanted to post the solution for anyone else who ran into it.

I discovered after setting up multiple stores that while Flat Rate and Free Shipping methods showed up on our second website, the Table Rates did not. The reason is because the table rates file was missing from the second website configuration.

Simple export the table rates .csv file from the store that works (you will need to select the actual store, rather than 'Default Configuration', under "change configuration scope"), change the configuration scope to your new store, and upload the .csv that you just exported.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your System -> Configuration

Then select the subdomain store. The drop-down in the upper left (usually)

Then go to the Sales -> Shipping Methods section. See if they are enabled or set to inherit from the default store.

Comment: everything is inherit, i've tried to enabled them and it still won't work.

Comment: Have u fixed this? i am having this problem